# highmap Data point click event breaks after zoom on a mobile (touch screen)

Tags: jquery, css, html, highmaps

Highmap Data point click event breaks after zoom on a mobile (touch screen)
**Any suggestions?** 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip.pointFormatter in conjunction with useHTML is still expecting a string as the return value and therefor should be used mainly for CSS/HTML formatting.
I suggest the use of your own HTML tooltips for more advanced stuff like buttons:

```
 Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Point.prototype, 'select', function (proceed) {
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    var points = mapChart.getSelectedPoints();
    $('tooltip-button-close').click(function () {
        points[0].select(false);
    }
   });
```

Demo: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info